# ajax formdata append does not work for key value style

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, form-data

why this code does not work ? how am I supposed to append additional data in formdata?

```
fd = new FormData();
fd.append("file_for_upload", file_blob_chunk);
fd.append("test", "testing");
fd.append("test2", original_file_name);

xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.open("POST", "files/index/" + file_name + '/' + file_part, true);
xhr.send(fd);
```

when I debug it, I can see the array for 'file_for_upload', but not for 'test' or 'test2'.

basicly usually you will use $_FILES and then it should show array of file_for_upload. It works that way. but now I need to add another one such as original_file_name. but it does not show the other array.

Is it possible because I only have one form for file upload in the html page, and don't have the other two textbox form?

Comment: The code seems alright to me. Could you elaborate more on what's not working, or set up a demo?

Comment: @bažmegakapa I edit the post, check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find those two in `$_POST`. Only files go into `$_FILES`.